# CS0234 C# The type or namespace name 'Slydeextender' does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, migration

I'm **migrating an old solution from VS2010 to VS2015**. In VS2010 I have no issues.

I created a brand new application in VS2015 from scratch and started to copy/paste the code needed (as it's an old app there are pieces of code I don't want)

This is how the error looks like

[image]

The references for the Web project are

[image]

Comment: That namespace does not seem to contain that type.  Is it possible that you've got code that's creating that type using that namespace?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The target framework is 3.5.

I should've added that in the description.

Comment: I fixed it by changing from `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SliderExtender` to `AjaxControlToolkit.SliderExtender` and adding a new reference to the project [AjaxControlToolkit, version: 3.5.40412.0]

Comment: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing from System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SliderExtender to AjaxControlToolkit.SliderExtender and adding a new reference to the project [AjaxControlToolkit, version: 3.5.40412.0]